# Using Threading vs Asynchronous programming on a server

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, server, multiplayer

I am developing a little multiplayer game in my free time in C#. 
I've read that Threading and Asynchronous programming are similar but which of them should I use when writing a server that is waiting for new connections and serving existing connections at the same time? 
 I took the asynchronous approach at first but then I read that it is mainly used for IO purposes. And that made me question if it's appropriate for a situation like this. 
Thank you.

Comment: Servers usually do lots of IO (most everything they do is in response to network traffic, which is IO).

Comment: I agree with @DaveM , you are doing IO in this scenario quite a bit

Comment: read some of Stephens blogs, https://blog.stephencleary.com/ and think are you doing CPU workloads or just waiting for network / io things or simple timers.  And then read the blogs again :)

Comment: but, as a general rule, if this is a web server, DONT SPIN A THREAD, its a bad pattern, if you really need to create a thread on the server todo some CPU work then read up on the right way todo this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be put simple, behind the scenes async/await can be threading - the framework decides based on your hints if the continuation task will run on the same thread or not, or to allocate a whole thread to a task if needed. There are threads and thread pools at the hands of the scheduler. But using Tasks is in general much more easy to manage than threads, and above all, much more performant. An OS thread is costly, a managed thread is not. Yes, it makes its best use in IO bound operations, but isn't network communication IO? Anyway, because of the above, if you use Tasks instead of treads you have the same synchronization tools at hands and more. Just as an example, both Kestrel and Katana servers are Task based.

Comment: And most importantly, the old Async programming model was _harder_ than using Threads directly, but the new Task-based Async model, including async methods and `await` is significantly _easier_ than using Threads directly.  In particular you can have a main loop that executes once per client _without_ having to dedicate a thread for each client connection.

Comment: The important difference that I saw between other IO and a server is that a DataBase push/pull takes a finite amount of time while the server is listening for incoming clients infinitely.

Comment: Imagine a lot (hundreds or much more) tasks that can run in parallel. If you are using async/await when possible (yes, modern DB apis support TPL), the scheduler is capable to optimize this, by switching to a task that has IO ready while the other is waiting for IO. It is more complicated to achieve the same with threads

Comment: Switching to a thread which has IO ready can also be done in kernel space when using IOCP, there's no need to use async/await to get that.

Comment: If you embrace `async`/`await`, then often [there is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) for much of the time.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the statement "the framework decides based on your hints if the continuation task will run on the same thread"?

Comment: @Enigmativity Read the link he gave.

Comment: @user743414 - What link?

Comment: Just as addition @ErikHosszu: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2015/09/10/tasks-are-still-not-threads-and-async-is-not-parallel/

Answer (score -3):

In general both can be used, because you have a lot of network IO. But I do not like async/await, because it forces you to use async/await nearly in your whole application.

The main difference between async/await and using a thread/threadpool is that async/await is performed by the calling thread and it's designed to deal with the delay, while the second one will do work on a free thread and to reduce costs of creating a thread it should make use of a threadpool.

Everything comes with a cost. Setting up the statemachine for async/await took time and setting up threads also took time. But using a threadpool reduces these costs.

Like others wrote async/await can use a thread, but in general it does not. 
A good designed gameserver will have one thread to handle incomming connections and a threadpool to handle communication with the clients.
I would advice you to go that way, because it's proven a lot of times, and that's the way you have to go when you want to handle thousands of clients or need a huge throughput.

Btw.: Spawning many Task's will give you the same problems you will get when spawning many threads and is therefore not a good solution. The keyword here is "context switch", you should read about that.

Comment: For a server application, it almost certain should be `async`/`await` throughout anyway. It's going to spend most of its time waiting for things to happen, and if it can do that without tying up any threads, so much the better.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It depends. A multithreaded gameserver doesn't wait the whole time, because it does a lot of calcuations. So it's not comparable to a web API for example which waits most of the time.

Comment: "second one is called by a free thread in the thread pool" - What? That's only if you explicitly ask for a threadpool thread.

Comment: @Enigmativity which I gave as the prefered way to go for this case. Btw.: changed the text to make it more clear.